# ionic select with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic + angularJS... I have created a select item drop down like this

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label" >
       Unit
     </div>
      <select id="unit">
        <option selected>Kilometer</option>
        <option>Mile</option>
      </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am wanting to get the value with angularJS... I have tried this..
The scope.convert is coming when I click a button.

```
$scope.convert = function() {

alert($scope.unit);
};
```

It outputs "undefined".. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.unit` is actually not defined in the scope, hence you get `undefined`. You have to define `unit` on the scope. Since this is an angular application, you can do it the angular way.

In your controller, you want to define a model to hold the value selected. Lets call this model `unit` like you are actually trying to do. Hence you can initialize this model to `Kilometer` in your controller.

`$scope.unit = 'Kilometer'`

Now you need an array of options. This can be set up in your controller as well.

`$scope.unitOptions = ['Kilometer', 'Mile']`

We use scope to expose our models to the view, hence in your view, you can access this models as follow:

`<select id='unit' ng-options="unit for unit in unitOptions">`

You will get a dropdown with 'Kilometer' and 'Mile'. You can select any one of them and your model `unit` will be updated.

```
//This should now work
$scope.convert = function() { 
    alert($scope.unit);
 };
```

Note: I left the `id` attribute on the `select` element to show it has nothing to do with the model in your controller.

Comment: Thank you so much! AngularJS is very foreign to me.

Comment: You welcome. AngularJS is fun. Enjoy the experience.